# Returning ids of a table where all values of other table exist with this id using all() or exists()

Tags: mysql, sql, database, dbms-output

I have three tables with following data

Table 3 :

```
Table1_id        Table2_id
1                1
1                2
1                3
2                1
2                3
3                2
```

Table 2 :

```
Table2_id        Name
1                A
2                B
3                C
```

Table 1 :

```
Table1_id        Name
1                P
2                Q
3                R
```

I have a problem where I need to return all table1_id's which have an entry for all Table2_ids's in Table 3.

ie. I want my output to be

```
Table1_id
1
```

I found a  solution using count().
But is there a way to use all() or exists() to solve the query?

Comment: But can't join do that for you? If you select * from tbl1 join tbl2 on tbl1 join and  tbl3 join on tbl1 and tbl2  ... thinking out loud, it seems it should give you what you asked for?

Comment: The answer is  - Yes. But i think using count() is the better way.

Comment: Why you think so? If exists count() top 1?

Comment: I think, not using count will be more complex and probably perform worse. But i'm not sure, and would like to see an other solution.

Comment: _"I found a solution using count()"_.... which is where in the question?

Comment: using count: `select table1_id from table3 group by table1_id having count(1) = (select count(1) from table2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `NOT IN` with excluding `LEFT JOIN` in a subselect with a `CROSS JOIN`

```
select *
from table1
where Table1_id not in (
    select t1.Table1_id
    from table1 t1
    cross join table2 t2
    left join table3 t3 using (Table1_id, Table2_id)
    where t3.Table1_id is null
)
```

VS using `COUNT()`

```
select table1_id 
from table3 
group by table1_id 
having count(1) = (select count(1) from table2)
```

Explanation:

The `CROSS JOIN`

```
    select t1.Table1_id
    from table1 t1
    cross join table2 t2
```

represents how `table3` would look like, if every item from `table1` would be related to every item from `table2`.

A (natural) left join with `table3` will show us which relations really exists. Filtering by `where t3.Table1_id is null` (excluding `LEFT JOIN`) we get the missing relations. Using that result for the `NOT IN` clause, we get only table1 items that have no missing relation with table2.

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for . . Thank You for the answer and the explanation as well :) @paulspiegel

Comment: I've been wondering if there is any way to use all() for that question :?

Comment: "`NOT IN` is an alias for `<> ALL`." [Subqueries with ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html) - So in fact, i'm alredy using `ALL()` :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM Table2 AS t2
CROSS JOIN Table1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Table3 AS t3
                  WHERE t1.Table1_id = t3.Table1_id AND        
                        t2.Table2_id = t3.Table2_id)
```

to get `Table1` records not having a complete set of entries from `Table2` in `Table3`. Then use `NOT IN` to get the expected result.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I've commented that the query does not yield the expected result. You have to use `NOT IN` to get the required output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) But i would like to know what exactly does select 1 from . . mean?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything actually. It's just a literal value returned and is all `NOT EXISTS` needs in order to be evaluated.

Comment: @rcb_sp, "MySQL ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference" [Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `EXISTS` and `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t3_out.Table1_id FROM Table3 t3_out
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
    FROM Table2 t2 INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.Table2_id = t3.Table2_id
    WHERE t3.Table1_id = t3_out.Table1_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Table2_id) = 3 )
```

Comment: Using count is against the rules ;-)